# Too many arguments given (expected 2) but dictionary tuple has a max of 2 values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, urllib

[image: Traceback]

the `urllib.request.urlretrieve(src,path)` line gives an exception (Too many arguments given(expected 2)) but I am getting those values from a dictionary where the tuples have all 2 values. Where am I going south?
Here is the code:

```
page_soup = soup(text, "lxml")
friends_div=page_soup.find("div",{"class":"j83agx80 btwxx1t3 lhclo0ds i1fnvgqd"})
img=friends_div.findAll("img")

users={}
for image in img:
    if image.parent.has_key('href'):
        parent=image.parent.parent.parent
        users[(parent.select("span")[1].text)]= image['src']

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders=[('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.41 Safari/534.7')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

usersrc=""
filename=""
print(max(len(item) for item in users.items()))

 for user ,src in users.items():
    path=f"C:\\Users\\Krist\\Desktop\\SnakeRecog\\Models\\{user}.jpg"
   print(src)
     print(path)
     urllib.request.urlretrieve(src,path)
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: That function takes 1-4 parameters, so 2 parameters shouldn't be too many.

Comment: Please also show what's actually in `src` and `path`.

Comment: However, this function is also documented as a legacy interface for Python 2 compatibility, likely to be deprecated in the future. You shouldn't use it in new code.

Comment: @Barmar Traceback posted

Comment: Please post that as text and include more of what you see. There should be prints for src and dest that would be interesting.

Comment: `src` should be a string, not a tuple.

Comment: Your dictionary should contain strings, not tuples.

Comment: `addheaders` should be 2 element tuples of `("name": "value")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP headers consist of name:value pairs. You need to list those pairs as tuples in `addheaders`.

```
opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.41 Safari/534.7')]
```